# If Then statement not working correctly

Tags: excel, user-interface, vba

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Label7 = Format(Sheets("DATA").Range("R8").Value, "Currency")
Label4 = Format(Sheets("DATA").Range("AO2").Value, "Currency")

If Label7 > Label4 Then
Sheets("DATA").Range("R8").Value = Sheets("DATA").Range("R8").Value - Sheets("DATA").Range("AO2").Value
'Label7 = Format(Sheets("DATA").Range("R8").Value, "Currency")
AdjustLevel
Unload act_Upgrade
Unload Upgrade_Lot

Load Upgrade_Lot
Upgrade_Lot.Show

Else
MsgBox "Sorry You Don't Have Enough Money", vbOKOnly
Unload act_Upgrade
End If
End Sub
```

When it runs my Label7 is greater than Label4 yet it still runs the Else statement.  I don't know why.

Comment: what data type is `Label7` and `Label4`? Also, what is the value inside R8 and A02?

Comment: This is a code behind UserForm (CBF)? Is `Label7` and `Label4` both a MSForms.Label?

Comment: See below. @RolandTumble gives a working answer, @jdigital spells out the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currency inside of a string will be compared as a string, meaning that $9 will sort (not compare) last compared to $10 because the character 9 is sorted after the character 1.  Convert it to a double.  When you take a string a and b and do a test on  a > b, you are really sorting to find out what comes first.

You should make sure your variables are numbers by declaring them:

```
DIM label8 as double, label7 as double
```

before manipulating them.

Comment: I believe label7 in being declared as Variant in your codeline.

Comment: One thing to note here: Doubles will work fine when you're checking INequalities, but they should be avoided if you need to compare equality--two seemingly-equal Double values can be different from each other _way_ down in the low-order digits. If one _must_ check equality on Doubles, it needs a Function that checks whether or not they're equal to a specified number of decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

Format returns a string but you probably want to perform a numeric comparison, not a string comparison.

Comment: I formatted it as currency.  So both labels are formatted the same and being evaluated.

Comment: @Mike, I also believe the problem is in the data itself. Add a `debug.print` for both values right before the `if` statement and let us know the values we have within each.

Comment: No, no, NO! **Format** returns a **String**. Period. What you've asked for there is "The String representation of the number, formatted according to Currency conventions." If you want to turn them into Currency-type values, see my Answer.

Comment: @RolandTumble, take it easy, folk. Your answer **IS** correct, indeed. Still, we're trying to make Mike understand *why* your solution works rather than provide a direct solution. I assumed Mike knows a little bit (and would like to know a little bit more) as he's not a One Topic VampireHelp guy.

Comment: Well, I've been chided twice here for blowing my cool--I s'pose I did. But responding to "Format returns a string..." with "I formatted it as currency" rubbed me the wrong way at that moment: When someone gives you (not provably wrong) information about how a feature works in a language you don't know well, you shouldn't claim that it works otherwise (which is how I interpreted it at the time). Apologies to any, specifically including Mike, who may have taken offense at my tone.

Answer (score 2):

The code posted is doing String comparisons (see Knox's Answer). To turn these values into variables of the Currency type, you'd need:

```
Private sub Foo()

Dim Label7 As Currency
Dim Label4 As Currency

    Label7 = CCur(Sheets("DATA").Range("R8").Value)
    Label4 = CCur(Sheets("DATA").Range("AO2").Value)

    If Label7 > Label4 Then
         'do something
    Else
         'do something different
    End If

End Sub
```

Things to Notice:

1. I've declared my variables (you **are** using `Option Explicit`, yes? And understand scope?).
2. I've used your variable names, which are **really bad** names for Currency values.
3. You will actually get a numeric comparison, rather than String, this way. Format will **not** get you there, as it **always** returns a String (see my Comment on jdigital's Answer).

Comment: Nah, no worries. The occasional well-placed, fact-based blow-out can do wonders.

Comment: I voted for your answer, above my own, since you comprehensively supplied code and supplied a well reasoned explanation.

Comment: @Knox--gosh, Thanks (that's sincere, _not_ snarky/sarcastic...).

Answer (score 0):

If the `Else` branch is executed then it can only be the case that `Label7 > Label4` evaluates to false.

Without knowing what the values are I can't say why this is a surprise to you but I am sure that VBA's if statement works perfectly.

Comment: I'm not saying the if statement isn't working correctly, I'm just wondering what I might be doing wrong.  The number in Label7 is like $700,000,000 and the number in Label4 is $7,000

Comment: @Mike Forgive me, I was taken in by your question title: "If Then statement not working correctly"